# The number of scalar additions required to compute $P(QR)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $P$, $Q$, $R$ be matrices of order $3\times5, 5\times7$ and $7\times3$ respectively. What is the number of scalar additions required to compute $P(QR)$?

Do we have any formula to compute this? If we had to square a square matrix of order $n\times n$ how will the results change? Thanks...

Comment: Professor Strang discusses this for nxn matrices at 27:00 in this lcture - http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-4-factorization-into-a-lu/ . How will we find for mxn matrices?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm

Comment: @Ritu Please give the answers to my below comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer = $ 126 $. To get every number in the matrix $QR$, we need $6$ additions and there are $15$ numbers like that. similar calculation for the next step gives $4$ additions repeated $9$ times. So , we need $ 6*15 + 9*4 = 126 $ additions.

Comment: how did we get 6 and 4 here? and is it any formula? What should one understand by the term scalar addition?

Comment: Since Q has 7 columns and R has 7 rows whem we multiply them to get a single entry of QR we have to add 7 elements for that we need 6 additions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $2$ matrices of the order m*n and $n*p$. The no. of additions required is given by the formula $m*p*(n-1)$. In the above question P(QR) 
no. of additions required for QR would be $5*3*(7-1)=90$
no. of additions required for P(QR) would be $3*3*(5-1)=36$
so total additions required for the above question would be $90+36=126$

Answer (score -1):

Just an observation is  that .. the dimension of the product Matrix P(QR) is $9(3 \times 3)$ and 9 is dividing 126 ...so from this way can we find the number of scalar addition of the matrix.